# does array.slice() make data more private?

Tags: javascript

If we return `arr`, `arr` can be mutated. Does returning a copy of `arr` allow for more data privacy?

Original code

```js
function foo() {
  let arr = [];
  function qux() {
    return arr;
  }
  return {
    qux,
  }
}

let qux = foo().qux;
qux();
```

Revised code. Here `qux` returns `arr.slice()`, a copy of `arr` instead of reference to original array.

```js
function foo() {
  let arr = [];
  function qux() {
    return arr.slice();
  }
  return {
    qux,
  }
}

let qux = foo().qux;
qux();
```

Comment: Well yes and no. If you return a copy, the outside world cannot change the values in the indexes of the private array. However, if any of the array elements are objects, then the outside world *can* change those objects (unless they're explicitly frozen or something).

Comment: To add onto that, you can perform a deep copy to prevent the outside world from mutating them

Answer (score 2):

"Private" is not the right word to use. Whether you slice the array before returning or not, the caller of the function will still be able to see the contents of what's returned. The caller can also examine the `foo` function itself by calling `.toString` on it. If you want actual privacy, [function implementation hiding](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-function-implementation-hiding) is at stage 2 and has a possibility of eventually being integrated into the language, but isn't here yet.

With your code, slicing does make the data more *controllable* - it means that, if you plan to use the array later inside `foo`, your module doesn't need to rely on the caller of the function not mutating the array.

That said, most would say that returning copies of objects everywhere they're returned is quite overly defensive. It'd be easier to say that consumers of your function/library should follow the implicit standard of **avoid mutating objects you don't own** unless explicitly permitted. If I'm using a library, and I get an object returned from the library, and I mutate it and the object (or something associated with the object) stops working as a result - that's on me, not the library.

Answer (score 0):

By "keeping private" I assume you mean that the array in the object cannot be changed from the outside, e.g. must remain immutable. To assure this in your `qux()` method you can do a deep copy. There are several ways to do a deep copy of an array with objects. The easiest one (not necessarily the fastest one) is a JSON stringify and parse:

```
  function qux() {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));
  }
```

Note that if your array items are all of a simple type like String, Boolean, Number you can use a `arr.slice()` instead of `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr))` to keep the original array immutable.